# How to validate JWT token with public keys provided in local json file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I have a REST microservice written in Spring Boot, which basically acts as a Resource Server. It will provide some data upon an endpoint call, but it would first need to validate access token (JWT).

The problem is that I do not have an authorization server, but I have JWKS file (I received it from the guys who created JWT in the first place) and it is stored as a local file.

Is there an elegant way to validate JWT token that I receive in the header of the request, using the local JWKS file ?

Comment: please read this article https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world. it has all the information you need

Comment: @inkredusk thank you for your answer. But how does this solves the problem with loading local JWKS file? That is simple hello world example with generation of JWT tokens. I need a way to validate existing token with public keys in JWKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it with the nimbus lib: `com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.31`

Assumes your JWKS contains an RSA public key which matches the kid in the incoming JWT.

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSASSAVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;

    JWKSet localKeys = JWKSet.load(new File("my-key-store.json")); // or classpath probably

    public boolean isSignatureValid(String token) {
        try {
            SignedJWT signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);
            JWK key = localKeys.getKeyByKeyId(signedJWT.getHeader().getKeyID());
            JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier((RSAPublicKey) key.toRSAKey());
            return signedJWT.verify(verifier);
        } catch (ParseException | JOSEException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```